# Generating-bijective groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

We may say that two finitely generated groups $G$ and $H$ are ***generating-bijective*** when there exist homomorphisms $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ and $\psi:H\rightarrow G$ such that, for each **ordered** generating sets $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$ of $G$ and $H$, resp. we can find ordered generating sets $\mathfrak h'$ and $\mathfrak g'$ of $H$ and $G$ resp. such that 
$$\phi(\mathfrak g')=\mathfrak h,\quad \psi(\mathfrak h')=\mathfrak g$$
Do there exist finitely generated groups $G$ and $H$ along with epimorphisms $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ and $\psi:H\rightarrow G$, such that $G$ and $H$ aren't generating-bijective?

Comment: "ordered" is not so important to emphasize: you just mean you can lift generating subsets (if it's ordered at the bottom, it becomes ordered at the top).

Comment: Restatement: let's say that $f:G\to H$ is an LPE (Lifting Property Epimorphism) if every generating subset of $H$ lifts to a generating subset of $G$ (i.e. is the 1-to-1 image by $f$ of some generating subset of $G$). Your question is whether there exist f.g. groups $G,H$ with epimorphisms $G\to H\to G$ such that there does not exist any LPE $G\to H$.

Comment: As a first basic remark, an example of epimorphism $G\to H$ such that there exists no LPE $G\to H$ is the projection $\mathbf{Z}\to \mathbf{Z}/5\mathbf{Z}$ (indeed, either $\{1\}$ or $\{2\}$ in $\mathbf{Z}/5\mathbf{Z}$ cannot be lifted to a generator of $\mathbf{Z}$).

Comment: @YCor: I emphasized "ordered" because the cardinal of a generating set is important in my problem, and this is considered in your new definition by "1-to-1".